# Visual Studio Code 1.34.0 ignores C# #if false construct

Tags: c#, .net-core, visual-studio-code, preprocessor-directive, ubuntu-19.04

I use the latest Visual Studio Code on Ubuntu 19.04 for .Net Core 2.2 C# development. It ignores the `#if false` code-block comment-out. What do I miss? Thanks.

```
#if false
    Console.WriteLine("Don't run this line");
#endif
```

But it runs and it not commented out in the IDE editor.

Comment: The code block is not commented out as expected. Debug still runs the code-block inside the `#if false #endif`

Comment: `#if false` to comment out a code block. What do you mean "comment out an `#if false`"?

Comment: `#if false` doesn't comment out anything, it hides that part completely from the compiler. Are you saying that this line compiles and runs, or that VS Code doesn't display it in gray? The first is a serious compiler issue. The second a syntax coloring issue

Comment: It doesn't grey it out.

Answer (score 0):

Using the line `#if true/false` will comment out the region below it (until `#endif`) if the condition is false. E.g:

```
#if false
Console.WriteLine("Hello");
#endif
Console.WriteLine("World!");
```

Will comment out the first writeline statement and only print "World!".

Comment: Exactly but it doesn't work in VSCode on Ubuntu 19.04. What do I miss?

Comment: What do you mean by doesn't work? Is the code inside the hashes commented out for you?